# Target Application configuration on OpenIAM (MyID)

Tags: single-sign-on

I work for an organization that is currently implementing the MyID authentication SSO web system in conjunction with OpenIAM.

When our end user signs into their MyID web portal, they will be able to select various web application that they will automatically be logged into once successfully logged into MyID. One of these applications in an automated time and attendance system.

The automated time and attendance system has two distinct buttons associated with it: one button to punch in/out, and another button to log into accrual and pay history.

Once logged into MyID, MyID will automatically punch you into the time and attendance system. However, there is no way to have MyID stop mid-login and allow the end user to either punch in/out or select the other button to view pay history.

Does anybody have any experience with this system and with a setup similar to this?

Here is a wiki on OpenIAM, but I can't find anything useful in it:
http://wiki.openiam.com/display/IAMSUITEV3/OpenIAM+Identity+and+Access+Manager+v3